# Sprint RestTemplate Kerberos authentication

Tags: spring, authentication, kerberos, ntlm, resttemplate

I have to call to a service with **NTLM authentication** (I think is the same as **Kerberos**) with Spring RestTemplate services. Someone knows how I could do that?

P.D: Sorry for my english.

Thanks...

Comment: For God's sake, NTLM is NOT the same as Kerberos! You weren't even able to use Google for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `RestTemplate` can be configured to use Apache HttpClient it uses the `java.net` classes by default (e.g. `URLConnection`).

The following code is untested but "should work"

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));
// maybe use "domain\username" instead
Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator("username", "password"));
...
<your-RestTemplate-call-here>
...
class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
    private String httpUsername;
    private String httpPassword;

    public MyAuthenticator(String httpUsername, String httpPassword) {
        this.httpUsername = httpUsername;
        this.httpPassword = httpPassword;
    }

    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        System.out.println("Scheme:" + getRequestingScheme());
        return new PasswordAuthentication(httpUsername, httpPassword.toCharArray());
    }
}
```